# how to count how many times a string occurs in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

MY DF:

```
c1 | C2 | C3
A  | B  | C
A  | B  | N
S  | B  | I
```

I want to know how many times `B` occured in column `C2`.

I want that output in a list

Desired output:

```
mylist=[3]
```

Comment: not `3` instead `2` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach, which could generalize well if you later want to know how many of two or more different values appear in a field, is to use `value_counts`:

```
df['C2'].value_counts()
Out[28]: 
B     3
Name: C2, dtype: int64

df['C2'].value_counts().tolist()
Out[29]: [3]

df['C2'].value_counts().to_dict()
Out[30]: {'B ': 3}
```

---

```
df['c1'].value_counts()
Out[31]: 
A     2
S     1
Name: c1, dtype: int64

df['c1'].value_counts().tolist()
Out[32]: [2, 1]

df['c1'].value_counts().to_dict()
Out[33]: {'A ': 2, 'S ': 1}
```

**Edit:**

To get `value_counts` list output ordered based on first appearance, you could use

```
df['c1'].value_counts().reindex(df['c1'].unique()).tolist()
```

Ex:

```
df
Out[65]: 
  c1  C2 C3
0  S  B   C
1  A  B   N
2  A  B   I

df['c1'].value_counts().reindex(df['c1'].unique()).tolist()
Out[66]: [1, 2]
```

Comment: Value count is working but It is giving a list from greater to lesser.
suppose if i have a column

col
B
B
C
C
C 
it will return [3,2] instead [2,3]